# Error: UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE Phonegap Installation

Tags: node.js, cordova, npm, ubuntu-13.10

I'm trying to install Phonegap in Ubuntu. The installation of NodeJS was successful, however I can't install Phonegap itself. Here is the error output of terminal:

```
test@test-VirtualBox:~$ sudo npm install -g phonegap
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/phonegap
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/phonegap
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/phonegap
npm ERR! Error: UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE
npm ERR!     at SecurePair.<anonymous> (tls.js:1350:32)
npm ERR!     at SecurePair.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
npm ERR!     at SecurePair.maybeInitFinished (tls.js:963:10)
npm ERR!     at CleartextStream.read [as _read] (tls.js:463:15)
npm ERR!     at CleartextStream.Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:320:10)
npm ERR!     at EncryptedStream.write [as _write] (tls.js:366:25)
npm ERR!     at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:219:10)
npm ERR!     at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:209:5)
npm ERR!     at EncryptedStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:180:11)
npm ERR!     at write (_stream_readable.js:573:24)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://bugs.debian.org/npm>
npm ERR! or use
npm ERR!     reportbug --attach /home/test/npm-debug.log npm

npm ERR! System Linux 3.11.0-14-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "phonegap"
npm ERR! cwd /home/test
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.15
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.18
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/test/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 175):

I got the same error, given I was behind a corporate firewall/proxy and my connection was passed the proxy's certificate.

In your command line run:

```
npm config set strict-ssl false
```

NOTE: that this is not best practice to blindly accept untrusted or invalid SSL certificates, which is what the command does (turn off certificate checking). You can run

```
npm config set strict-ssl true
```

to turn it back on.

ref: https://thomashunter.name/blog/npm-ssl-errors/

Comment: Thanks .. it worked in case installing Angular CLI with npm also.

Comment: THANK YOU! I spent the entire morning trying to find the solution

Answer (score 41):

This can be fixed without disabling strict SSL, however it is non-trivial.

**Find** the certificates actually being used, likely you're [behind a corporate SSL intercepting proxy](http://www.zdnet.com/article/how-the-nsa-and-your-boss-can-intercept-and-break-ssl/). You might be able to use a browser, some CLI tool etc. I ended up running `certmgr.msc` in Windows as the certificates are distributed via Group policy and export as p7b files.

**Convert** the certificates if necessary, I used openssl tool to convert from p7b to PEM (aka .crt)

```
openssl pkcs7 -print_certs -inform DER -in /mnt/adam/certs/my-company-root.p7b -outform PEM -out my-company-root.crt
```

**Merge**, if there is more than one certificate, into a single PEM file, [taking care to order from leaf to root.](https://serverfault.com/questions/476576/how-to-combine-various-certificates-into-single-pem)

```
cat my-company-leaf.crt my-company-intermediate.crt my-company-root.crt > my-company-single.crt
```

**Configure** npm at the certificate file

```
npm config set cafile my-company-single.crt
```

(or globally)

```
sudo npm config set -g cafile my-company-single.crt
```

Comment: just tried it, and it's working ! For me it's way better than disabling ssl at all... You don't know what may happen in the future. Thanks for your solution :)

Answer (score 9):

running

```
npm config set strict-ssl false
```

solved my problem.

I'm using Vagrant (Linux precise32 Ubuntu ), and Windows 7 as host.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can also disable SSL check in your code using node environment variable :

in your index.js file, add :

`process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = '0';`

Note that this is not a good habits as it will not try to check the validity of https certificate

Answer (score 2):

in case anyone is as clumsy as me, I got `UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE` on `npm install` when I forgot to add the `git+` before the url of my project.

I had

```
npm install --save https://myserv.er/my/project-path.git
```

instead of

```
npm install --save git+https://myserv.er/my/project-path.git
```

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure that root has configuration properties.**

When using *sudo*, you're running under the environment configured for root. Root may not have the same node configuration, and may not be aware of your certificates. Try passing your environment configuration to root with *-E*:

```
$ sudo -E npm install -g phonegap
```

Answer (score 0):

It happens to me. It turned out my cooperation proxy restricted the official NPM registry, and returned a blocked HTML warning. Just updated my npm registry to cooperate one, and the problem was solved.