# npm ERR! code UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE

Tags: node.js, angular, command-line-interface

**While installing angular-cli after installing nodejs, I got this error**

npm ERR! code UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE
npm ERR! errno UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcli failed, reason: unable to verify the first certificate

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

**Can anyone help how this error can be fixed? I have to work on a project and i am unable to find the solution.**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20747817/error-unable-to-verify-leaf-signature-phonegap-installation

Comment: Thank you for answering. but this error occurred while installing angular/cli after node.js

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVED. Thank you so much