# npm UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE Verdaccio

Tags: ssl, npm, certificate, certbot, verdaccio

I have a private Verdaccio server under https protocol.
My certificate has been generated by certbot and recently I had to renew it.
But now npm throw me a error

```
npm ERR! code UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE
npm ERR! errno UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE
npm ERR! request to https://myserver.com/-/v1/login failed, reason: unable to verify the first certificate

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-02-21T16_54_52_853Z-debug.log
```

I don't want to `npm set strict-ssl false` for security reason
How can i fix that ?

Comment: Do you think i have to reset the certbot certificate in openSSL ?

Comment: It seems the same issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20747817/error-unable-to-verify-leaf-signature-phonegap-installation