# Can't install cordova with npm

Tags: node.js, cordova, npm

i use the code npm install -g cordova and the error are shown below:

npm ERR! code UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE

npm ERR! errno UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE

npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/ionic failed, reason: unable to verify the first certificate

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     C:\Users\alip\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-03-04T04_11_33_400Z-debug.log

i already try to use npm uninstall -g npm and install back using npm install -g npm@2.12.1 but still the same error occur. can anyone help me. I used this to develop mobile apps

Comment: Are you behind corporate proxy/firewall? Check this Q&A - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20747817/error-unable-to-verify-leaf-signature-phonegap-installation

Comment: thanks a lot it worked!!

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
npm cache clean -- force
```

and then:

```
npm install -g cordova
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please add some context or more explanation about your answer. Also, read about [How to Answer a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to learn how to write effective answers.