# Error: unable to verify the first certificate after setting up an id_rsa

Tags: reactjs, npm, ssh, next.js

I suddenly faced an error when starting a nextJS app after running the following commands:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "myemail@example.com"
```

After setting up the passphrase I cannot run `npm run dev` and get the following issue:

```
{
  code: 'UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE'
}
```

I also tried disabled the ssl on npm but it is still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE` should be an error seen with certificate issue for HTTPS URLs ([like here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59730178/6309)), *not* SSH.

In other works, your SSH key should not be involved at all.

If you have `git+https://` URLs in your dependencies:

- either you can fix your certificates ([example on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13913941/6309))
- or you can use, for some URLs, an [SSH one instead of HTTPS](https://gist.github.com/taoyuan/bfa3ff87e4b5611b5cbe#gistcomment-3270122) (which would then rely on your SSH key)