# npm install lodash issuse

Tags: node.js, npm, installation, npm-install

I'm trying to install lodash through npm, and get this eror.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Usually this is a certificate issue, and you can do a workaround with

```
npm config set strict-ssl false
```

Note that this isn't a secure solution and you should reference [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20747817/error-unable-to-verify-leaf-signature-phonegap-installation)
and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23788564/npm-add-root-ca) for further explanation on investigating the root cause.