why 'npm install' and 'npm ping' do not answer and then throw error?
I have problem with npm.
When I try to execute npm install, it waits for about couple of minutes with this:
long pending
and then respond with:
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: cosmetology@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: vite@undefined
npm ERR! node_modules/vite
npm ERR!   dev vite@"^5.1.4" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer vite@"^4.2.0 || ^5.0.0" from @vitejs/plugin-react@4.2.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@vitejs/plugin-react
npm ERR!   dev @vitejs/plugin-react@"^4.2.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! C:\Users\artem\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2024-04-19T20_31_20_378Z-eresolve-report.txt
Also I checked npm connection with 'npm ping' and it is not responds either.
C:\Windows\system32>npm ping
npm notice PING https://registry.npmjs.org/
npm ERR! code UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE
npm ERR! errno UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/-/ping?write=true failed, reason: unable to verify the first certificate
("--force" and "--legacy-peer-deps" don't help)
OS: Windows 10
Tried to uninstall and install again nodejs, still does not works.
Recently I installed docker with WSL, may be it could impact on that?
By the way: I have linux on my virtual machine, I decided to try in there, and npm ping, npm istall works there. So there are no problems with connection etc.

Do you use an antivirus, a firewall or a proxy? The second problem looks like broken certificates or a man-in-the-middle. You could try to clean the npm cache.

Are you able to navigate https://registry.npmjs.org/ in a browser? Are there firewalls or vpns? This is primarily related to network related problems, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20747817/error-unable-to-verify-leaf-signature-phonegap-installation
